# Advertise a House for RENT - how to describe it positively when its completely run-down

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I have a house that I need to rent out but it's old and completely run-down.
The house will be demolished in a year or two when the owner is ready to develop the land.

What buzz words or phrases can I use that describe something old/bad/derelict but in a positive light? I don't want to lie but I don't want to advertise it as a s#!t hole either, haha.

Things like "A house with character"

Comment: "Not in an active volcano zone" might be viewed as a positive.

Comment: "Beats camping on the freeway"; "Would appeal to mycologists"; "Conveniently located near multiple street corners".

Comment: "Fixer-upper" is, as far as I know, the standard. It covers a wide range of sins, from basically sound but needing a complete remodeling, to something best served by demolition.

Comment: Unfortunately, "fixer-upper" has almost no appeal to a renter. If the advertisement were for a buyer, you might say "Perfectly sound, usable lot for sale; included structure should come down easily."

Answer (score 5):

It's not small and rundown- it's a compact charmer.

It's not in a bad neighborhood- it's in interesting surroundings.

It's not old and out of style- it's a vintage structure with period appeal.

It doesn't have inadequate electrical power and bad pipes- it has preserved traditional features.

It doesn't have inadequate security- it has an inviting presence.

It doesn't have leaky windows and doors- it has an airy and open feel.

It doesn't have a dirt front yard with a car up on blocks- it has low-maintenance landscaping.

There are probably more, but maybe that will get you started.

Comment: It ain't infested with fleas, it's pet friendly. The roof doesn't leak, it's includes some utilities. It's not lead paint, it's a sweet paint job. It's not no heat, it's energy efficient. It's not a deathtrap, It's offers life-altering experiences. It's not a lie, when someone believes it.

Answer (score 2):

**Still standing** is a half-full glass truth.

Answer (score 0):

If the house were on sale you could use the following sugar-coated expressions:

- With the right tender love and care this charming [year] home will spring back to life.
- Now this is a home with lots of potential.
- A house that allows you the freedom and creativity to do anything you want.

But the property needs to be rented, so I would emphasize the aspects which might sway someone to live there. The cheap rent; the facilities nearby, e.g train station, schools, hospitals, parks; the number of bedrooms; the low rent; the vicinity to the city centre; the friendly neighbourhood; the affordable rent; a spotless home in need of a few repairs; the ridiculously low rent...